# Typescript: How to define a function that references an object using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, nested-generics

How does one define a function based on keys of an object using generics. The actual use case has more keys and values so I prefer not to define it explicitly.

```js
const obj = {
    a: {
        1: 1,
        2: 2,
        3: 3,
    },
    b: {
        1:1,
        2:2,
        4:4
    },
};

// My best attempt
const fn = <T extends keyof typeof obj>(key1: T, key2: keyof T) => {
    return obj[key1][key2];
}
```

Error: `Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type '{ a: { 1: number; 2: number; 3: number; }; b: { 1: number; 2: number; 4: number; }; }[T]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some more generic parameters:

```
const obj = {
    a: {
        1: 1,
        2: 2,
        3: 3,
    },
    b: {
        1:1,
        2:2,
        4:4
    },
};

const fn = <O, T extends keyof O, U extends keyof O[T]>(o: O, key1: T, key2: U) => {
    return o[key1][key2];
}

fn(obj, 'a', 1) // ok
fn(obj, 'a', 6) // error
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXBtrqQIxFkA0JpOATEfTXbgMxFsu4C%203O8IllY4K1WnUbMJpACwFZEvph4BuTJgD0mmAFkAnjHgBTaPihRjAWwAOUTKEiwAZmFQwAPAHkqMACowxgAelmAAJhAwANbG%20iDOMD4wAKqBIcbhkTFxCV4A2n4AugB8ABQgREnZFP6%202YwpAJSoxcSkjmZ47iB51YW9sfSF6jwaruVIvgDkeFO%20ZM3acFGY4wiI07O%20AGyLOsYATgcgB5hAA)

Comment: Thanks, this works! For reference, without the additional o parameter, it would look like this `const fn = <T extends keyof typeof obj, U extends keyof typeof obj[T]>(key1: T, key2: U) => obj[key1][key2];`